# find a probability measure such that $(W_t + \sqrt{3t+2})_t$ is a Wiener process wrt to $P$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Like the title says: suppose $W_t$ is a Wiener process on the space $(\Omega, F, Q)$. We want to find a different probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$ such that
$$ (W_t + \sqrt{3t + 2})_{0 \leq t \leq 1}$$ 
is a Wiener process with respect to $P$. I wanted to use Girsanow's theorem to do that. It tells us how to pick $P$ if we want something of the form
$$W_t - \int_0^t Y(s) ds$$
to be a Wiener process. However in our case $\sqrt{3\cdot 0 + 2} = \sqrt{2} \not=0$ so I'm a bit puzzled, cause I can't use this thm directly. I'm pretty sure this should have a quick solution since it came up as a test question on an exam in introductory stochastic analysis, but I can't seem to figure it out - any insight will be appreciated!

Comment: You can apply Girsanov with $W_t + \sqrt{3t+2} - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Obviously one should try to realize $(W_t+\sqrt{3t+2})$ as a Wiener process **starting from** $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Siméon took the words out of my mouth (comment box). Note that $\sqrt{3t + 2} - \sqrt{2} = \int_0^t y(s) \, ds$ where $y(s) = \frac{d}{ds} \sqrt{3s+2}$.

Comment: right, but acording to my definition a Wiener process has to start from $0$, can I find a $P$ that will satisfy this? if so is there a 'formula' for it?

Comment: @mm-aops: isn't the answer obviously no?!

Comment: well, seems likely, but that's not so obvious to me - I don't really know much about stochastic processes, a friend gave me this question, indicated her problem and I just looked up the definition so I was puzzled, because it stated precisely that it has to start from $0$. thanks for the input anyway, I'll just tell her to ask her professor what he meant, cheers!